# Does it have to be counted as wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently took a test and did these steps of a proof: where $u$ and $v$ are vectors, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal, $I$ is the identity matrix.

$$Q\vec{v}=I(-2\vec{u}\vec{u}^T)\vec{v}$$
$$=I\vec{v}-2(\vec{v})(\vec{u}\vec{u}^T)$$
$$=\vec{v}-2u(\vec{v}\vec{u}^T)$$
$$=\vec{v}-2\vec{u}(0)$$
$$=\vec{v}$$

Got marked off for interchanging order of multiplicity. Said I must use $\vec{u}^T \vec{u} = 1$ and $\vec{u}^T \vec{v} = 0$.

I guess I don’t understand why I can’t? I feel like the proof was valid.

Comment: Please format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) - this will make it much easier to read, and therefore much more likely to be answered.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative: in general $AB\ne BA$.

Comment: $2v(uu^t) \ne 2u(vu^t)$.

Comment: Also $vu^T\neq 0$

Comment: Your very first equation appears to be misparenthesized.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you’re confusing the dot product $\vec u^T\vec u$, which is a scalar, with $\vec u\vec u^T$, which is a square matrix. Not only is the multiplication not commutative here, the product $\vec v\left(\vec u\vec u^T\right)$ isn’t even defined: if $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are elements of $\mathbb R^n$, then you’re trying to multiply an $n\times1$ matrix by an $n\times n$ matrix.

The second step of your derivation, in which you exchange $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, is also unjustified, the preceding notwithstanding: matrix multiplication is in general not commutative. It is, however, associative, so the first step in the derivation would be to rewrite the second term as $2\vec u(\vec u^T\vec v)$ and then use the fact that the two vectors are orthogonal.